# Determining whether or not random variables are correlated

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-expectation, correlation, covariance

I'm working on the following problem:

> Consider random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that exactly one of them is
>   equal to $0$. The other then takes the value $1$ or $-1$ with equal
>   probability (ex: if $X = 0$, then $Y = 1$ or $Y = -1$ with equal
>   probability).
>
> Are $X$ and $Y$ correlated?

Here is my work so far:

By definition,

$$
\text{corr}(X, Y) = \frac{\text{cov}(X, Y)}{\sigma_x \sigma_y}.
$$

By definition, $\text{cov}(X, Y) = \mathbb{E}\left[ (X - \mathbb{E}[X])(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y]) \right]$. Let us compute $\mathbb{E}[X]$. We can write

$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[X \mid X = 0] \mathbb{P}(X = 0) + \mathbb{E}[X \mid X \neq 0] \mathbb{P}(X \neq 0).
$$

From the problem statement, we know that $\mathbb{P}(X = 0) = \mathbb{P}(X \neq 0) = 1/2$ and $\mathbb{E}[X \mid X \neq 0] = 0$. It is also clear that $\mathbb{E}[X \mid X = 0] = 0$. Thus, the covariance expression reduces to $\text{cov}(X, Y) = \mathbb{E}[XY]$.

**My question**: how do I proceed from here? I just want to know whether or not the two random variables are correlated, which reduces to determining whether or not $\text{cov}(X, Y) = 0$. However, I'm not sure how to go about evaluating what I have left.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is $X$ the random variable that is equal to $0$ here? Or is it $Y$? If $X=0$, then $\mathbb{P}(X=0) = 1$, and not $\mathbb{P}(X = 0) = 1/2$.

Comment: Wait, I may be misunderstanding. I think that the problem statement is that for any outcome, exactly one random variable is equal to $0$ (so $XY=0$). Is this true?

Comment: It is always the case that exactly one of $X$ and $Y$ is equal to 0 (each occur with probability $1/2$, they are never both $0$).

Comment: Yes, exactly one of $X$ and $Y$ is zero. But given that, how do I go about computing $\mathbb{E}[XY]$?

Comment: If one of them is always $0$, then their product $XY$ will always be $0$, so $\mathbb{E}[XY] = 0$.

Comment: Oh haha I feel dumb now.

Comment: PS: From the problem statement you *don't* know $\Bbb P(X{=}0)~=~\Bbb P(X{\neq}0)$.  You do know that always exactly one of $X$ or $Y$ is zero, but you don't know the probability of it being $X$.  Still, this doesn't matter because the expectation of $X$ is zero (as $X$ is either zero with some probability or, when not zero, is one or negative one with equal probability).